# Is it possible to restore a SQL Server Linux Backup on SQL Server Windows

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, linux, sql-server-2017

I am running SQL Server in docker on a mac. I have taken a SQL Server backup from windows and restored it in the mac SQL Server docker instance. Now I want to take a backup from the SQL Server docker instance and restore it back to windows. When I attempt to restore on Windows I am getting a "System tables sysfiles1 is corrupted".
Is it possible to take a back up from SQL Server Linux and restore it on SQL Server Windows?

Comment: Could this be a file copy issue...like ASCII vs. BINARY?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just validated it. Yes. Not only is it possible, other than using the WITH MOVE to change where the files are located, there's literally nothing special involved. I tested it using a shared volume to get the backup out of my docker instance. I also tested it using the docker file copy command. Both worked just fine. It's possible that the backup is corrupt or that the versions are off.

Comment: Not working for me though Grant. I am creating the backup in the container, copying out to the mac os, then copying over to windows. tried a couple of times. always "System table sysfiles1 is corrupted"

Comment: @mikelus That doesn’t mean the problem is going between Linux and Windows. It sounds like you have corruption no matter where you try to restore.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was able to get it to restore on another docker SQL Server instance so it's working in Linux, just not on windows. so it's not actually corrupted

Comment: Same version and build number?

Comment: @mikelus Well, SQL Server doesn't make up errors about corruption for funsies... and I still don't believe the operating system has anything to do with this at all. Can you provide more details, like version/build backup was taken, version/build you're restoring to, the restore command you're actually running, the _whole_ error message including error numbers, what type of filegroups (e.g. filestream / in-mem) and how many files the database has? Does this happen for _just this database_ or _all database_? Could you post the .bak file somewhere (or any .bak file that repros)?

Comment: Yeah, what Aaron says. Something else is going on besides a simple move of a valid backup file from a container to another location.

Comment: I've got the same error in the same situation, so WITH MOVE is definitely not sufficient to solve this. Restore works perfectly fine with the exact same file on a fresh Linux container, so there's nothing wrong with the file.

Like the other answer says, this might be specific to LocalDB.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce when trying to restore to localdb.

Restoring on a full SQL Server works fine.

Comment: I was facing the same issue for LocalDb. but after installing sql server 2019, it is working fine. thanks